# Cannot get monodroid working on Vista: Could not locate Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, xamarin.android

I have installed MonoDroid 1.0.1.10323 today but every time I try to run my "Hello World" program, it does not compile. The error message:

C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Novell\Novell.MonoDroid.Common.targets(180,2): error : Could not locate Android SDK.

I have read that it expects the sdk to be installed to C:\android-sdk-windows. Mine is installed at C:\Java\android-sdk-windows (didn't envision using MonoDroid a few months ago). Nonetheless, I changed the sdk path in vs2010 (tools > options > mono for android > settings) to the correct path. That didn't work. I tried updating MonoDroid's registry keys to the correct path. No dice. I even moved the sdk to C:\android-sdk-windows and that didn't help either.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Sean

Comment: i should also mention that i've tried restarting vs2010, restarting windows and uninstalling/re-installing monodroid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you up the log level of MSBuild, it should tell you all the places it is checking for the SDK, and what it ends up finding in the Output window:

Tools->Options->Project and Solutions->Build and Run->MSBuild Project Build Output Verbosity

Comment: good idea. it was tripped up looking for the platform-tools directory. it seems this is from a newer sdk than i had. re-installed the jdk and android sdk and it compiles now! thanks again!